# Accessing a request parameter already declared in constructor in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, events, listener

I want to access a Request parameter in my Listener.
I found this solution (to declare it in the constructor) but it should be only initialized in handle method?

I want to access my request in the `onNewUser` method

my code

```php
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->request=$request;
}

public function handle($event)
{
    //
}

public function subscribe($events)
{
    $events->listen(
        'eloquent.creating: App\Models\User',
        'App\Listeners\UserSubscriber@onNewUser'
    );
}

public function onNewUser(User$user){
    userService::userModification($user, 'creating',$this->request);
}
```

Comment: The `_construct()` method is called at the start of any instance of a class. bot just for one method (`handle()`). Also you can access the request via the laravel helper `request()`.

Comment: What is `$this->request`? Have you setted up the property `$request` on the class?

Comment: yes ,it's a `Request $request`

Comment: @N69S how can i access my `$request` via the laravel helper `request()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set `$request` as your class's property? Like so:

```
class Something {

    public $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function onNewUser()
    {
        return $this->request; // That way, you can initialize it here
    }

}
```

Comment: did you see the comment above of N69s. he said that we can only access `$request ` variable in `handle` method. Solution? or it's fine we can access it everywhere in the class

Comment: If you pass the `$request` variable when you instanciate the object, and create the property as I said, then you can access it whatever you want inside the class. However, the best solution here is what @N69S suggested in the first place: just use the laravel helper `request()`